# How can I set the width of a select object using jquery.ui.combify

Tags: jquery

I need to set the displayed width of a combobox using jquery.ui.combify.
Searching the web didn't come up with an answer and I've tried various combinations of css parameters on the jquery call, (eg. .css('width','200')) but all fail.
My test code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/jquery.ui.combify.css" />
  <script src="includes/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.ui.combify.js"></script>
</head><body>
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['cmd']))
  {$cmd = $_REQUEST['cmd'];}
else
 {$cmd = '';}
$act = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'PHP_SELF', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
switch ($cmd)
{
  case 'SUBMIT':
    debugbox("Selected value:  ",$_POST['MySelect']);
    $cmd="";
    echo "<form id='retry' name='retry' action=$act method='post'>";
    echo "<button type='submit' name='cmd' value=''>Go Again</button>";
    echo "<button type='submit' name='cmd' value='exit'>Quit</button>";
    echo "</form>";
    break;
  case 'exit':
    break;
  default:
    echo "<form id='selform' name='selform' action=$act method='post'>";
    echo "<select id='MySelect' name='MySelect' size='2' onchange='debug(this.value)'>";
    echo "<option>Some Option</option>";
    echo "<option>Some Other Option</option>";
    echo "<option>Yet another Option</option>";
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<button type='submit' name='cmd' value='SUBMIT'>SUBMIT-IT</button>";
    echo "</form>";
    break;
}
function debugbox($m1,$m2)
{
  echo "<script language=\"Javascript\">
    <!--
    var msg1 = '$m1';
    var msg2 = '$m2';
    var a = msg2.length;
    if (a > 0)
    {
      msg1 = msg1 + '\\n';
      msg1 = msg1 + msg2;
    }
    alert(msg1);
    // -->
    </script>";
}
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#MySelect").combify();
  });
  </script>
</body></html>
```

The working form has several combo elements and they need to be different sizes.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Combify prepends `CombifyInput-` to your `MySelect` id so the code below should do the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#MySelect").combify();
        $('#CombifyInput-MySelect').css('width','300px');
    });
</script>
```